# Show different <Button> element depending on ternary

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to show different HTML Elements depending on a ternary and I don't know the
proper syntax to it.

```
{valuePro ?
                {
                <Button
                    className="proButton"
                    secondary
                    onClick={triggerFileSelectPopup}
                    style={{ marginRight: "10px", zIndex: (isVisible ? 6 : 1), marginBottom: "8px" }}
                >
                    Change
                </Button>
                <Button
                    className="proButton"
                    onClick={onDownload}
                    style={{ marginRight: "10px", zIndex: (isVisible ? 6 : 1), marginBottom: "8px" }}>
                    Confirm
                </Button>
                 } :
                {
                <GenericButton
                    secondary
                    onClick={triggerFileSelectPopup}
                    style={{ marginRight: "10px", zIndex: (isVisible ? 6 : 1), marginBottom: "8px" }}
                >
                    Change
                </GenericButton>
                <GenericButton
                    onClick={onDownload}
                    style={{ marginRight: "10px", zIndex: (isVisible ? 6 : 1), marginBottom: "8px" }}>
                    Confirm
                </GenericButton>
                }
}
```

I want  to show when valuePro is true and  when valuePro is false.

Comment: Is the question "How do I only return the buttons with the `proButton` class"?

Comment: Use paranthesis `()` instead of curly brackets `{}` to wrap the statements. And a [`React.Fragment`](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) to wrap the multiple JSX Elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do that by actually picking up what component do we want to render:

```js
const ButtonComponent = valuePro ? GenericButton : Button;
```

You also have common styles in there which u can extract for better readability here:

```js
const calculatedStyles = { marginRight: "10px", zIndex: (isVisible ? 6 : 1), marginBottom: "8px" };
```

Your code can look like this:

```js
              <React.Fragment>
                <ButtonComponent 
                    secondary
                    onClick={triggerFileSelectPopup}
                    style={calculatedStyles}
                >
                    Change
                </ButtonComponent>
                <ButtonComponent 
                    onClick={onDownload}
                    style={calculatedStyles}>
                    Confirm
                </ButtonComponent>
              <React.Fragment>
}
```

Note that u can replace `<React.Fragment></React.Fragment>` with `<></>`

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping multiple nested elements in a `<>` should make it work if that's the error you're caught up with.

```
{valuePro ?
                <>
                    <Button
                        className="proButton"
                        secondary
                        onClick={triggerFileSelectPopup}
                        style={{ marginRight: "10px", zIndex: (isVisible ? 6 : 1), marginBottom: "8px" }}
                    >
                        Change
                    </Button>
                    <Button
                        className="proButton"
                        onClick={onDownload}
                        style={{ marginRight: "10px", zIndex: (isVisible ? 6 : 1), marginBottom: "8px" }}>
                        Confirm
                    </Button>
                </> :
                <>
                    <GenericButton
                        secondary
                        onClick={triggerFileSelectPopup}
                        style={{ marginRight: "10px", zIndex: (isVisible ? 6 : 1), marginBottom: "8px" }}
                    >
                        Change
                    </GenericButton>
                    <GenericButton
                        onClick={onDownload}
                        style={{ marginRight: "10px", zIndex: (isVisible ? 6 : 1), marginBottom: "8px" }}>
                        Confirm
                    </GenericButton>
                </>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{valuePro ?
                <>
                <Button
                    className="proButton"
                    secondary
                    onClick={triggerFileSelectPopup}
                    style={{ marginRight: "10px", zIndex: (isVisible ? 6 : 1), marginBottom: "8px" }}
                >
                    Change
                </Button>
                <Button
                    className="proButton"
                    onClick={onDownload}
                    style={{ marginRight: "10px", zIndex: (isVisible ? 6 : 1), marginBottom: "8px" }}>
                    Confirm
                </Button>
                 </> :
                <>
                <GenericButton
                    secondary
                    onClick={triggerFileSelectPopup}
                    style={{ marginRight: "10px", zIndex: (isVisible ? 6 : 1), marginBottom: "8px" }}
                >
                    Change
                </GenericButton>
                <GenericButton
                    onClick={onDownload}
                    style={{ marginRight: "10px", zIndex: (isVisible ? 6 : 1), marginBottom: "8px" }}>
                    Confirm
                </GenericButton>
                </>
}
```

try this since ternary if wants to get only 1 element

Answer (score 0):

You can move this logic to a new function then it will work.
you can try something like this:

```
const buttonRender = () => {
   return valuePro 
      ? <> ...probuttons </> 
      : <> ...nonprobuttons </>
}
```

note that you need a `Fragment` or `<>` to return multiple components